# plot a line graph with two axes in vb6

Tags: input, vb6, charts

I want to plot a line graph from two arrays in VB6, e.g.

```
x(1 to 3) =1,2,3
y(1 to 3) =1,2,3
```

... with axes containing values x=1,2,3 and y=1,2,3.

I only know this command:

```
picture1.line(x1,y1)-(x2,y2)
```

... but these don't have any axes option to label, etc. I am getting a graph with that, but no axes - just a line with the slope of corresponding chosen points.

Please give me code to name axes, or any other better way to generate a chart in VB6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VB6, you can take advantage of the automatic scaling available to the Form and PictureBox controls.

Add the PictureBox "Picture1" to your form, and place two Line controls, LineX and LineY *into* the PictureBox. These will form the axes. Add the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DrawLines(x() As Single, y() As Single)

    Dim nIndex As Long

    ' Ensure x() and y() are the same size.
    If UBound(x) <> UBound(y) Then
        Err.Raise 1000, , "x() and y() are different sizes"
    End If

    ' First line:
    If UBound(x) < 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Draw line between first two coordinates.
    Picture1.Line (x(1), y(1))-(x(2), y(2))

    ' Subsequent lines:
    For nIndex = 3 To UBound(x)
        ' Draw line to next coordinate.
        Picture1.Line -(x(nIndex), y(nIndex))
    Next nIndex

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    SetupPictureBox Picture1

End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_Paint()

    Dim x(1 To 4) As Single
    Dim y(1 To 4) As Single

    x(1) = 15!
    y(1) = 15!

    x(2) = 45!
    y(2) = 45!

    x(3) = 15!
    y(3) = 45!

    x(4) = 15!
    y(4) = 15!

    DrawLines x(), y()

End Sub

Private Sub SetupPictureBox(ByRef pct As PictureBox)

    ' Set up coordinates for picture box.
    pct.ScaleLeft = -100
    pct.ScaleTop = -100
    pct.ScaleWidth = 200
    pct.ScaleHeight = 200

    ' Set up coordinates for the X axis.
    LineX.X1 = -100
    LineX.X2 = 100
    LineX.Y1 = 0
    LineX.Y2 = 0

    ' Set up coordinates for the Y axis.
    LineY.X1 = 0
    LineY.X2 = 0
    LineY.Y1 = -100
    LineY.Y2 = 100

End Sub
```

Note that the two axes automatically paint themselves. The painting code for the triangle is contained in the PictureBox's Paint event.